# Scroll inside the table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have a simple html table inside a page, all I need is to make this table scrollable from inside and keep the table header static.

I also need to make this table fit the whole screen, so the footer is visible. I don't need to specify a static height, as this screen will be displayed on high resolutions and it makes no sense to apply specific height in pixels.

Here is the fiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/3L4zb7cf/

Code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <table class="containertbl">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="header">
                        This is the Header for the website.
                        This is the Header for the website.
                        This is the Header for the website.
                        This is the Header for the website.
                        This is the Header for the website.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="content">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th><th>col6</th><th>col7</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td><td>details 1</td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="footer">
                        This is the Footer for the website.
                        This is the Footer for the website.
                        This is the Footer for the website.
                        This is the Footer for the website.
                        This is the Footer for the website.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
        .header {
            background-color: navy;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: navy;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .content{
            padding: 7px;
        }
        .content table {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .content table thead tr th{
            color: aliceblue;
            background-color: darkgoldenrod;
            border: 1px solid #98bf21;
        }

        .content table tbody tr td{
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #98bf21;
        }

        .tbl{
        }

        .container{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        .containertbl {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body{
            margin: 0;
            font-family: cursive;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
        height: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
```

in `.content` class.
uptated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3L4zb7cf/1/

edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/3L4zb7cf/4/

In this second exemple, with those property, I think you can do what you want:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: I mentioned that I don't need to specify height to the content as it should be sctreched over the screen.

Comment: I reached that far, but couldn't keep the table header static. I wonder if that's technically possible

Comment: mmh, without any javascript? I feel the task will be hard.

Comment: Fixing the header could be done with other table on top of the other but fixed. It's not a clean solution but still valid.

Answer (score 1):

To make the table header fixed you should change the

```
position : fixed;
```

But in your case it's conflicting with other css properties. So I would suggest to create another table for the header and let it be in fixed position.

Try this fiddle :

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/uu1x8262/)

Comment: I meant the "Table" header, this way only the "Page" header is fixed but the table header and the page footer are not.

Comment: then change the position to your table header to fixed. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I know this method and tried it. Still does not deliver the output I'm trying to reach. You can update the fiddle example to show your solution. The problem here is that after the scroll the table header will be hidden under the page header. Is there a way to make the table header fixed as well ?

Comment: I think you should take another table just for the header. And make it's position fixed. Try this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/uu1x8262/ if it's the solution i'll update the answer.

Comment: your anwer is helpful, though the other answer will be more useful for other visitors. so Thumbs up!