# css overflow-x: scroll on ul

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table using ul li, however despite what I try the only way I can get the x overflow to scroll is when I manually set the width, however this is not practical as I don't always know how many rows will be in the table.

question 1: 
 how do I achive 'overflow-x:' scroll on this?

question 2: 
 Should I be using 'a href' or 'onclick' around the ul ?

```css
#Results {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px dotted #4b545f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 114px;
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 230px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 230px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 230px);
  height: calc(100% - 230px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#Header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow-x: visible !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#Header > ul {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px dotted #4b545f;
  padding: 0 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: visible !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  clip-parent: #ResBody !important;
}
#Header > ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 114px;
  max-width: 114px;
}
#ResBody {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
#ResBody > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-left: 1px dotted #4b545f;
  border-right: 1px dotted #4b545f;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #4b545f;
  padding: 0 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: visible !important;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#ResBody > ul > a > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 114px;
  max-width: 114px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#ResBody > ul:hover > a > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 114px;
  max-width: 114px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #0b75b2;
}
```

```html
<div id="Results">
  <div id="Header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">aa</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">bb</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">cc</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">dd</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ee</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ff</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">gg</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">hh</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ii</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">jj</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">kk</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ll</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">mm</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">nn</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="ResBody">
    <ul>
      <a href="#a#">
        <li><a href="#">aa</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bb</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">cc</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dd</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ee</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ff</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">gg</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">hh</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ii</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">jj</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">kk</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ll</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">mm</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">nn</a>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *I'm trying to create a table using ul li..*: Why? `table` element is already there to semantically represent tabular-data. `ul`s purpose is to represent list-data. Why go thru all hoops and loops to do something with an element which is not suited for the purpose?

Comment: `width:100%` of `#Header > ul` should be fine. you don't need to manually set `width` as it will get the parent width.

Comment: Because I need sticky headers for the table and I would like to see if it is possible to achieve this as I have seen similar things being achieved on the web.

Comment: I already answer a question that is similar to your

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086419/scroll-inside-the-table/27086458#27086458

Comment: width:100% of #Header > ul seems to push the li elements down to the next line =/

Comment: @krisph: Here is an example of sticky headers and scrolling table: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/njss2t05/3/